# How do I remove my changes on OpemCms 10.0.1?

Tags: opencms

I'm currently working with OpenCms 10.0.1 and have just created a "sub-sidemap" under "Sidemap" for a "Content page". How do I undo this? Nothing is published yet, so it is not published and only visible to people who can edit the page.
Question formulated differently: How can I delete / reuse my change?
I'm using FireFox.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made.

Answer (score 0):

it is not easy to answer your question, because I am not sure what you really want to do.

If you just want to delete your newly created folders you can easily delete them by right-clicking on the folder icon and choose *"Delete"*. As your folders have never been published, they are deleted instantly. You could also change the folder type by selecting *"Advanced" --> "Change type"* in the context menu.

In case of an already published file or folder you can choose *"Undo changes"*. This will undo all changes since the last publish.

If you are unsure, what kind of changes where made, you can compare versions by choosing *"History"* from the context menu.

Last but not least you can as well restore already deleted files by choosing *"Advanced" --> "Restore deleted"*.

HTH

Have a nice day!

Best regards
Kai

Comment: I had to go to Explorer and there I could right click on the edited folder and select undo changes. That was not possible in the side editor.

Thank u :)